# How to determine number of replicate in DOE mathematically?

Tags: experiment-design

Actually, almost all of agriculturist define the number of replicate in their design of experimentally is based on subjective approach like experience, field condition, and so on. Even we know that the replicate (n) should be n>=2. I want to hear all your opinion regarding this issue. Is there a specific formula to determine number of replicate mathematically?

Comment: By replicates, do you mean replicated centre points?

Comment: No this replicate is the number of replication used in each treatment.

Answer (score -1):

Usually in mini tab there is a method to calculate the sample size. This depends on the std Deviation you want. For example what is the max difference between 2 readings you will accept, before you say they are significantly different. Based on this you can calculate the sample size which indirectly gives you the number of replicates

Comment: It would greatly improve the answer if You explained what formulae are used.

Comment: and how it would provide the number of replicates